# Duplicate column names extracted from MS ACCESS DB on pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to export MS ACCESS DB Table to CSV using pyodbc.

I have written a statement to get the field names of a table as.

```
print([r.column_name  for r in cur.columns(table='Office_Address_List') ])
```

Actually this table has only 3 columns as

- First Name, Last Name, Shares

A sample record for this as:

```
[('Andre', 'Green', '2,000'), 
('Andy', 'Bonness', '3,000')]
```

But on executing the above statement it returns 6 columns as-

Table Name : Office_Address_List

- First Name, Last Name, Shares, First Name, Last Name, Shares

Why it is giving the 6 columns although it has only 3 columns.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Try opening the database in Access and running a "Compact and Repair Database" operation on it.

Comment: Yes I tried it - opening in MS ACCESS and clicked on Compact and repair database. but still exports duplicate set columns. i have 70 files, only 4 files are having this duplicate column issues.

Comment: If you identify a table that consistently produces the duplication and use Access to export the table (Definition Only) to a new empty database file do you see the same duplication when you reflect the columns from the new file?